# Getting CentOS initialization script from console?

Tags: centos, scripting

I'm encountering a very weird problem. Last year a friend of mine coded a CentOS initialization script to create proxies. It was working perfectly, but a couple of months ago all my hard drives got terribly damaged and I lost all the data. The only place I still have the script on is a server I set up last year (running CentOS of course) which was initialized with that script. I currently have the access to the server via console, is there any way to get back the initialization script?
Thanks!

Comment: If you have access via the network and ssh just use scp?

Comment: @RamanSailopal yeah but I'm not an expert and I have idea what directory I should look into, can you help me?

Comment: So you don't know where the script is on the server?

Comment: No, that's the whole point. Sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: If you know the name of the file then you can run the command "find / -name <filename>" You would ideally need root permissions for this though.

Comment: I don't know the name of the file either. I hoped CentOS automatically stored initialization scripts in a certain directory but it doesn't seem to be like that :(